# How to set up nightwatch.json to be cross platform

Tags: nightwatch.js

Currently in my  `nightwatch.json` I am set up fine for running on my mac:

```
{
  "src_folders" : ["specs"],
  "output_folder" : "tests/e2e/reports",
  "custom_commands_path" : "",
  "custom_assertions_path" : "",
  "page_objects_path" : "",
  "globals_path" : "",

  "selenium" : {
    "start_process" : true,
    "server_path" : "bin/selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2.jar",
    "log_path" : "",
    "host" : "127.0.0.1",
    "port" : 4444,
    "cli_args" : {
      "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "bin/chromedriver 2",
      "webdriver.ie.driver" : ""
    }
  },

  "test_settings" : {
    "default" : {
      "launch_url" : "someurl",
      "selenium_port"  : 4444,
      "selenium_host"  : "localhost",
      "silent": true,
      "screenshots" : {
        "enabled" : false,
        "path" : ""
      },
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "javascriptEnabled": true,
        "acceptSslCerts": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However the driver for chrome will need to run `chromedriver.exe`. What is the best practice way of resolving this? Do I need 2 config files? I would prefer not to have this as I will need to have extra checks for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution is to use a nightwatch.conf.js file, ie:

```
module.exports = (function (settings) {

  //Setting chromedriver path at runtime to run on different architectures
  if (process.platform === "darwin") {
    settings.selenium.cli_args["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = "bin/chromedriver 2";
  }
  else if (process.platform === "win32" || process.platform === "win64") {
    settings.selenium.cli_args["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = "bin/chromedriver.exe";
  }

  return settings;

})(require('./nightwatch.json'));
```

Comment: so how are you testing Edge or IE on your Mac?